# What timeout value should I set to avoid problems in a REST based Android application?

Tags: android, rest, timeout, httpclient, settimeout

It may sound stupid but. I've set the timeout to 5 seconds and testing with a 3g connection it seems to be too little when in my experience it really sounds like an eternty.

What's a common use value for users not to desperate and keep the things together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really no special, commonly used values for something like timeouts. A value that works for one user may not work for the other. The important thing from a UX perspective is, when the timeout does occur, the user is informed of:

1. A timeout has occurred.
2. The next appropriate action to recover from it, such as, restart the app, wait a while, contact support etc.

via unambiguous error message.

Comment: F***... Maybe I wanted just to take out that from the error handling. I'll and user messages for that.  Thank' a lot!!

Comment: That sounds cleaner. Otherwise, you're gonna end up with "magic number" floating around. By the way, if you like the answer, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Did it for... I knew this was kind of a subjetive question

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound stupid, but it depends on the interaction between your app and the server. Unlike a router based timeout, some routers begin their calculation when they begin to do the work (Heroku comes to mind). In this case, anything under 30 seconds is good.

Comment: Testing in openshift it seems like one login takes millis and the next may take up to 8 seconds. Maybe it's not the propper setup for a real mesure.  In my job it's not an reasonable value but I usually have real hardware and clusters capable on serving real loads...  I'm not able of measuring these things... Should I move to another provide?

Comment: @eduyayo That's interesting. That means there's a good chance that it's a server side issue. It's not necessarily the host, could be server side script that could be running asynchronously or in the background. What stack (LAMP, Nodejs, LEMP) are you using? How is your raw API responding? Try using something like POSTMAN to see if you can POST and GET requests after authenticating. I have a feeling it's not your app code, but the server config.

Comment: Plain java with token preauth. Local deployment goes regular and times are all even. Up there it is imposible to estimate